# How do I translate the tab menu of a view?

Tags: 7, views

I cannot translate the tabs menu shown in a view. Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Dis you enable the menu translation module?

Comment: yes i have enabled it but it allows me to translate the menus not the tab menu in view like i uploaded the image above.i can not get those menus in the navigation

Comment: Can you check in admin/config/regional/translate/translate if you find the tab titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate and search for the tab titles you want to translate. Since you have the required modules installed you should be able to find them there.